# CSS cannot pad text within a nav bar defined as an unordered list

Tags: html, css, padding, navbar, spacing

I have a website with a nav bar defined using a few divs and an unordered list.

```
    <!--Nav Bar-->
    <div class="nav-blur"></div>
    <div class="nav">
        <img class="logo" src="img/rectangle.png">
        <ul class="links">
            <li class="link text"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="link text"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="link text"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="link button"><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Currently, the last link in the nav bar is a button, different from the others which are plain text.

[Nav Bar Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X391.png)

Here is my CSS to style such:

```
.nav-blur {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);     
    filter: blur(10px);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}


.nav .logo {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    height: 95%;
    width: auto;
}

.nav .links {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 11px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.nav .divider {
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav .links .link {
    display: inline;
}

.nav .links .link a {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
}

.nav .links .link a:hover {
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
}

.nav .links .button {
    background-color: rgba(103, 155, 193, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav .links .button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(103, 155, 193, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav .links .button a {
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My current problem is that although I can adjust the padding both right and left of the text inside the button I cannot adjust the padding vertically. I have tried to add the spacing I need with both padding and margins neither of which have any effect.

```
.nav .links .button a {
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav .links .button a {
    padding-right: 7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
    margine-top: 5px;
    margine-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have also tried incasing the text inside a spereate div which managed ro royally mess up my nav bar.

What CSS would I need to add inorder to give some verticle padding to my text inside the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical padding is ignored by `inline` elements...which is the default `display` type of anchor links.

Set the links (and the `li`) to `display:inline-block`.

```
.nav .links .link a {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: normal;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.nav .links {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 11px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  float: right;
  background: #000;
}
.nav .divider {
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.nav .links .link {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav .links .link a {
  color: whitesmoke;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav .links .link a:hover {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
}
.nav .links .button {
  background-color: rgba(103, 155, 193, 1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.nav .links .button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(103, 155, 193, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.nav .links .button a {
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="links">
    <li class="link text"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="link text"><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="link text"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="link button"><a href="#">Get Started</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I change the links to block rather than inline the contents no longer align horizontally across the nav, rather they align vertically to the right of the window.

Comment: Amended to `inline-block`. Display`block` works on the anchors providing the `li` are `inline-block` - https://jsfiddle.net/0qpau8Ld/1/

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank You